# Why is the hydride ion negative?

Tags: ions

Recently, I saw a video about sodium hydride and it saw it was made up with $\ce{Na+}$ ions and $\ce{H-}$ ions. My  problem is: aren't all hydrogen ions positive? And in what conditions can $\ce{H-}$ occur?

Comment: Sodium and most other metals have a lower electronegativity than hydrogen. Thus, in metal hydrides the metal transfers an electron to hydrogen leading to a negatively charged hydride ion, $\ce{H-}$, and a positively charged metal ion.

Comment: It's negative simply because it has more electrons (2) than protons (1), so the main question is how it can occur.

Comment: It seems likely that you'd be interested in this; there are actually negative ions of the alkali metals as well, [alkalide ions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkalide).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And in what conditions can $\ce{H^{−}}$ occur?

In any phase. The hydride ion however doesn't stick around for long in water since it's *such* a strong base. First, hydrogen isn't that electronegative to start with, so tacking on an extra electron isn't helping with its stability. Second, combination with an hydrogen proton, $\ce{H+}$, is highly entropically favorable because the product, $\ce{H2}$, is a gas.

The $pK_a$ of $\ce{H2}$ has been estimated to be ~35 so that speaks a lot to the strength of the hydride ion as a base.